# How to display username in the url after successful login in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm creating an E-commerce website.I want to set the username dynamically for a user after login. My code:

```
namespace EcommerceDbFirstApproch.Models
{
    public class ExampleRoute : Route
    {
        public ExampleRoute(string url) : base(url, new MvcRouteHandler()) { }

        public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            var url = httpContext.Request.Headers["HOST"];
            var index = url.IndexOf(".");

            if (index < 0)
                return null;

            var subDomain = url.Substring(0, index);

            if (subDomain == CookieHelper.GetCookieValue(CookieKeys.UserName))
            {
                var routeData = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
                routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Product"); //Goes to the User1Controller class
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index"); //Goes to the Index action on the User1Controller

                return routeData;
            }

            return null;
        }       
    }
}
```

Its not working. Am I missing something?

Example - admin.localhost/Product/Index

I want to this type of Url after login dynamically.

Comment: Just as a side note: It seems that you are getting the username from a cookie. Remember that anyone can change the values in the cookies on their machine, so after logging in, I could set the username in the cookie to another users username. I do not know what you are using the username for, but it does'nt look to safe to me.